# imagecreatefrompng merge 2 PNG images into one PNG php

Tags: php, png

I am working on php code where i merge 2 png images into one image. Actually it is school id project. Where i put profile pic on school card.

```
$profile = imagecreatefrompng("profile.png");
//imagealphablending($profile,true);
//imagesavealpha($profile, true);
imagecopy($card,$profile,850,280,0,0,1180,700);

imagepng($card,"output.png",9);
echo '<img src="output.png" />';
```

[card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIjbp.png)

[profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk5V8.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvcoY.png)

how i can remove black ............ i tried all solution on stackoverflow and google but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell the system the width and height of the student photo correctly, otherwise the system will apply black as the background color when merging the two photos.

For PHP, you may use the `getimagesize` function to get the correct width and height.

So the code is :

```
<?php
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('HIjbp.png');
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('Uk5V8.png');

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('Uk5V8.png');


imagecopy($image_1,$image_2,850,280,0,0,$width,$height);

imagepng($image_1, 'result.png');

echo '<img src="result.png" />';

?>
```

Working version here:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/SO_20220413.php

Comment: `getimagesize` can return false.

Comment: of course, if the image does not exist.

Comment: Which may be the case since we dont have OP full dev stack.

Comment: if the image does not exist, do you think the merging operation makes sense ? On the other hand, please click the working version of my answer. Thanks

Comment: Good point. On that thought, "canvas" needs to be set to transparent on "how i can remove black"